# VBA Code for transferring the data input to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

txtName is not showing in another sheet. This is my code. The rest is working but the txtName.Value is not appearing. No error appears when running the vba. pls help thanks

I tried other variable and other textbox but to no avail

```
Dim wt As Worksheet
Set wt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("History")
Dim e As Long

e = wt.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wt.Range("A" & e + 1).Value = Date
wt.Range("B" & e + 1).Value = ""
wt.Range("C" & e + 1).Value = "Deployed to"
wt.Range("D" & e + 1).Value = txtName.Value
wt.Range("E" & e + 1).Value = "New Asset"
```

Comment: This is impossilble to tell without more information. What *is* txtName? Where is your code located? When is it triggered? Have you checked `txtName.Value` with the debugger? Do you use `Option Explicit?` Do you use `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: txtName is the name of one of my textbox. I have a button "Add" which is whatever the user input in the textbox, it will automatically input in "History Sheet". All other cell is working except for the wt.Range("D" & e + 1).Value = txtName.Value

Comment: Where is the textbox located? On a sheet? On a form? If on a sheet: Is it a form control or an ActiveX control? Where is your code located? In a regular module? Worksheet module? Code of a Form? What shows the debugger when you put a breakpoint on the line and inspect the content of `txtName.Value`?

Comment: Unless you have a `txtName` on multiple sheets, it shouldn't even be needed to use the worksheet name prior to it. Worked fine for me without when having the textbox and button on the same sheet.

Comment: A quick solution is to make a global variable on top of the page. write `public myTxtName As String` and when ever you use your txtName, make sure to store the name to your global variable like `myTxtName = txtName.Value`. That's the best answer I can give out of the poor fact you written. Hope it helps.

Comment: You cannot use `History` as a sheet (tab) name since it's a *"reserved name"*. A *Subscript out of range* error should occur when running your code. The question is why this error is not occurring (probably `On Error Resume Next`). Show the complete code so we can draw some conclusions. If the code name of the worksheet is `History` then reference it with `Set wt = History` or just use `History` instead of `wt`.

Comment: I'm able to name a sheet `History` and use OP's code without issues (in Dutch Excel) @VBasic2008 , so this might not be the problem either.

Comment: Hi this one shows on the debugger Object variable not set (Error 91)

Comment: @Notus_Panda That's a surprise I wasn't aware of. Out of curiosity, can you also use *Historie*?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Also tried different name but still the same

Comment: @FunThomas textbox is located on a form. code is located in "Add" command button (code form). When putting a breakpoint on the line it only says Object variable not set (Error 91) though

Comment: I assume that the name of your textbox is not `txtName`. **(a)** Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the code (always do that) **(b)** If you have any `On Error Resume Next` statement in your code, remove it. It's hiding errors, not solving errors. **(c)** In a form, always use the keyword `Me`, eg `Me.txtName` - the VBA editor intelligence will help you choosing the correct name.

Comment: I've re-tested your code as is (txtbox and button in Userform) and it works just fine for me. Didn't need to use `Me.txtName.Value` either so I suppose there must be a typo in the name or in your actual code? @VBasic2008 That was too literal, for Dutch it'd be "Overzicht"

Comment: @Notus_Panda: `Me` is not needed, but it helps because Intellisense can help you. And it makes the code more readable

Comment: the name of my textbox is txtName. Option Explicit is also above my code and I don't have On Error Resume Next. I also tried Me.txtName.Value before but still the same. I do have similar codes with that but it works fine. I don't know whats wrong with txtName.Value since I don't see any error on it. With that code, Range ABCE is working fine but that txtName.Value is not

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but I feel maybe images might assist in understanding things better.
The Userform1 is newly added, textbox is added and button as well. As you can see, the TextBox got the name "txtName"

[image]

[image]

After giving the button a name "btnAdd" (I didn't bother changing the caption, that's cosmetics and not necessary for a test), we go into the code of said button
[image]

I did change the sheet name since I went into the English version (so not everything would be in my native tongue); as you can see: the intellisense @Funthomas mentioned is active when using `Me.` , `btnAdd` is already visible

[image]

When typing `Me.t`, txtName should already be visible if you named it correctly.

[image]

Hope this visual aid helped.
Ps: probably best not to check your last row based on the column that you leave empty when adding your new asset unless that's the intended effect.